# SP13 vs SP16 / O365 - Is SharePoint fully responsive to enable the use of different devices?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

My current environment is built with an on-premises SP13 farm and I administrate and design a range of subsites for different departments for a small company.

I design in CSS and JS to create the customization to enable responsive pages and general accessibility.

We are in the early stages of migrating to SP16 within O365 but information seems thin on the ground.

Would anyone be able to either direct me to the relevant Microsoft article or ideally give me your own personal insight?

**My question: Is SharePoint fully responsive to enable the use of different devices?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a short answer:** No the SharePoint is **not** fully responsive!!

By default, the SharePoint on-premise is **not** fully responsive. Meanwhile, you can

1. Enable `the Mobile view` to get the same result. To try out mobile view on a device, use the following procedure:

   - Open a SharePoint site on the device.
   - In the upper right corner of the site, tap Settings  Office 365 Settings button , and then tap Site settings.
   - Under Site Actions, tap Manage site features.
   - Set the Mobile Browser View to Active. (The default setting is Active.)
   - To switch back to mobile view, tap Settings  Office 365 Settings button , and then tap Mobile view.For more details check [Configure a SharePoint site for mobile devices](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-SharePoint-site-for-mobile-devices-ddf28727-3bfe-4b56-951d-c97204eac475?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)
2. Or you will need to customize your Master Page to enable responsive design as mentioned at [Implementing your responsive designs on SharePoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2013/04/01/implementing-your-responsive-designs-on-sharepoint-2013/)

Also Check

- [Responsive Web Design v Device Channels in SharePoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2013/04/01/implementing-your-responsive-designs-on-sharepoint-2013/)
- [Announcing Responsive UI Package for SharePoint on-premises (2013 and 2016)](https://dev.office.com/blogs/announcing-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint-on-premises-2013-2016)

Regarding Sharepoint Online, By dint of The `modern experience` and `SPFX`, it currently offers **some** responsive features in the SharePoint environment.also you can create custom responsive web parts with SPFX. for more details check [IMPLEMENTING RESPONSIVE SOLUTIONS WITH THE SHAREPOINT FRAMEWORK & THE MODERN EXPERIENCE](https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2017/04/14/implementing-responsive-solutions-with-the-sharepoint-framework-modern-experience/)

Comment: I am not allowed to say thanks or plus one - so i will just say this is the best answer